# 3D surface plot in R with plot3D or plotly

Tags: r, surface, plot3d

I want to produce a 3D surface in R where y is flux, `x` is Age and `z` is precipitation. I have a range of age between 0 and 152 and a range of precipitation 0 and 2600.

I also have two functions where flux is function of Age or Precipitation:

```
Flux= 0.387217066*(Age^0.328086337)*(exp(-0.004177033*Age)
```

and

```
Flux= 1.117997*(1-exp(-exp(-5.426564)*(Preci-(-220.745499))
```

What I want to achieve is something a bit like [this](http://www.oakdaleengr.com/plot3d.gif):

[image]

I have tried to do it with the package `plot3D` in R without success (see below)

```
Age<- as.matrix(seq(0:152)) 
Preci<-as.matrix(seq(from=10, to=2600, by=17))
Flux= as.matrix(0.387217066*(Age^0.328086337)*(exp(-0.004177033*Age)) - 1.117997*(1-exp(-exp(-5.426564)*(Preci-(-220.745499)))))
surf3D(Age, Preci, Flux, colvar = Flux, colkey = FALSE, facets = FALSE)
```

I got this error message

```
Error in if (is.na(var)) ispresent <- FALSE else if (length(var) == 1) if (is.logical(var)) if (!var) ispresent <- FALSE : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Comment: `ggplot2` doesn't do 3D plots, but you can use `rgl` or `lattice::wireframe`.  `emdbook::curve3d()` might be a useful wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a start, using `emdbook::curve3d()` as a wrapper for `lattice::wireframe` (see the `sys3d` argument to `?curve3d`).  It's not obvious to me why it would make sense to combine your functions of flux as a function of age vs precip by subtracting one from the other, but as that's what you did above ...

```
## for readability, put numeric values in a separate vector
params <- c(a0=0.387217066,a1=0.328086337,a2=0.004177033,
            p0=1.117997,p1=5.426564,p2=-220.745499)

library("emdbook")

curve3d(with(as.list(params),
          a0*(Age^a1)*exp(-a2*Age)-
            p0*(1-exp(-exp(-p1)*(Preci-p2)))),
        varnames=c("Age","Preci"),
        xlim=c(0,200),ylim=c(10,2600),
        sys3d="wireframe",
        col="gray",
        zlab="Flux")
```

[image]

`curve3d` also returns a list with components `$x`, `$y`, `$z` that you can use as input to other 3D graphing frameworks.

Comment: @ Ben Bolker. I agree that it does not make sense to o combine my functions of flux as a function of age vs precip by subtracting one from the other. I am more looking at the interaction. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: that's really a scientific/engineering question, not a statistical one.  Depending on the situation adding or multiplying *might* make sense, or you might need more information to determine the right combination.